# How to enable SCSS highlighting and intellisense in <style> tag?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

I have a web component that contains 3 tags. `<template>`, `<style>` and `<script>`. The extension of the file is `.html`. Highlighting and formatting in template & script tags is working as expected. Also the style tag has not an issue if I write pure CSS in it.

```html
<template>
  <p>
    Hello {{data.name}}!
    <a href="#">This is invisible</a>
  </p>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  p {
    color: red;
    a {
      display: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<script>
  class {
    data = {
      name: "fehmi",
    };
  }
</script>
```

I know Vs code has built in scss extension.
[image: Vs code SCSS plugin]

But it is only working if the file extension is `.scss`. How can I make it work in the `<style>` tag? I want to use nested rules and condition logic without getting syntax errors and loosing intellisense.

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: Nope. I am trying to use it with native web components.

Comment: I think you'll have to change your entire configuration in settings.json for every css to act like scss formatting then

Comment: But this file is not a CSS file. It is an html file that contains `<style>` tag in it. As far as I know we can only assign file extensions to languages via `settings.json`

Answer (score 1):

I have used this plugin. All you will need to do is to add is `lang="scss"` to the style tag.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sissel.scss-style-tag

I know this is pretty much a link-only answer so let me know if you need help configuring it.

Comment: I tried that days ago but It didn't work for me. Is there a special configuration to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Configure language mode to "vue"(or "svelte", these two mode both support ,  and ) seems solve the problem.
You can configure file association for the format of web-component.